# Add variable to beginning of line, not using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file where I'd like to add a string in the beginning of the line, however, it has special characters and sed complains about that.

The warning I get is:

```
sed: 1: "s/^/curl curliian.bxss ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'b'
```

So I tried to escape the dot:

```
dirnamer="$(dirname $1 | sed 's/\./\\./g')"
```

Which didn't work, so I tried to escape the `b`, which didn't work either. So yeah, this is what I do right now:

```
sed -i '' "s/^/curl $dirnamer/g" ~/desktop/download
```

But it seems there's alot of problems to do with with sed, because of special characters. What's a better method?

Comment: when sed complains about `b` being a *bad flag* its not talking about the one following that `.`. its talking about `s/^/replace/gpb` where *`gpb`* are *substitution flags* and *`b`* is not valid. but you can just do: `sed "i\\n$b"` - though you might lose any backslashes in `$b` if you dont double them up, and if `$b` contains newlines you'll need to backslash escape those, too.

Comment: I know, but I am was not using a b flag.

Comment: well, you were. somewhere in your variable is `/b`

Comment: @mikeserv That's correct, I should have edited the variable to escape that too.

Comment: Please show us your actual input and the sed command you used. We can't tell you what you need to escape if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: `printf %s\\n "$var" | sed 'H;1h;$!d;s/[/\\]/\\&/g;s/\n/\\&/g;s|.*|s/^/&/|' | sed -f - infile >outfile` should work for anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk command works fine.

```
awk '{print "curl $dirnamer|" $0;}'
```

Or doing this to the variable before:

```
sed 's/\/b/\\b/g' | sed 's/\/t/\\t/g'
```

Comment: dont bother looking for `[bt]` - the problem is `/` in both cases. `s/[\/]/\\&/g'` is good enough for a substitution field of an `s` command with a `/` delimiter to handle any variable that doesnt contain a newline.